# Connect to Tor network with ruby

Tags: ruby

how can I  configure Ruby web client to request web pages using Tor ?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's like specifying proxy server for your HTTP connection. I don't know how it works in Ruby. But it will not be different from [configuring browsers](https://wiki.torproject.org/noreply/TheOnionRouter/TorifyHOWTO/WebBrowsers). Just set proxy server setting to `127.0.0.1:8118`.

Answer (score 14):

I had to use this Gem http://socksify.rubyforge.org/ then I was able to do something like this

```
TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9050
reply = Net::HTTP.get URI.parse("www.google.com")
```

Obviously with the Tor proxy running.

Comment: So in order to use Tor through Ruby you have to have the Tor client downloaded and running?

Comment: Yes this won't work unless the client is running.  Also verify its SOCKs port is set properly.  When I downloaded the latest Tor browser my port was 9150 (as opposed to 9050 which is listed above).

Answer (score 2):

Created a Gem, maybe can help others: https://github.com/brunogh/tor_requests

Answer (score 1):

You just need to work with the [Proxy class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M000672). As Ivan says above, get Tor running then point Net::HTTP.Proxy at the correct localhost address and you're golden.