# How can I fake my IP address

Tags: ruby, ip, open-uri

I have a sprider collect data from some web site.but it offen be denied.

I think it basis of my IP address.

how can I fake my IP address. or have a another way to avoid be denied.

thx.

Comment: You avoid being denied by respecting the terms and conditions of the websites you scrape.

Comment: are you paying attention to directives in the ROBOTS file?  Also to terms and conditons of use?  some sites prohibit any kind of automated access to the site without prior permission.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you can do is try to access the end point through a proxy server. If the end point is tougher and can detect if you're coming through a proxy, you can try proxy chaining, or better still try something like tor. Look at this question - [Connect to Tor network with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959138/connect-to-tor-network-with-ruby) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to use a proxy, or to ask your ISP/hosting provider to give you a new one (and I suspect they probably won't, or if they do, they won't do it too often.)

If a site is blocking your IP address because you're running a spider on it, you should maybe think about how often you go to that website and how much traffic you cause the site. There's a reason they're blocking your IP (if they are.) Maybe change how often you go to the side with the spider, and also determine whether or not you should be (though I don't have any details on the site, so I can't comment on that)